# How to use jQuery inside ReactJs Project jQueryscrollSpeed.js plugin for full page scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use jQueryscrollSpeed.js plugin but I could not found the solution for this.
I have try using ref method but not get good result.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
class App extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    $(function() {  

      // Default
      jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800);

      // Custom Easing
      jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800, 'easeOutCubic');

  });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <p ref={"toggle"}>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, minima. Accusantium illum quam qui, natus eum laudantium vero ex. Vero.</p>
      </div>

    )
  }

}
export default App;
```

I need solution for this
[Github jQueryscrollSpeed.js plugin](https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed)

I need to use scrollspeed in my reactjs project.

Comment: i think first you have to add scroll speed plugin CDN link into index.html which is placed inside the public folder in your project

Comment: than, where I can use $(function){ .... } I have seen the doc reactjs but not understand properly how I can add this plugin without event listener

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below:

```js
const elementName = document.getElementById('elem');

elementName.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
  top: 400,
  behavior: 'smooth',
}));
```

I hope it would help you out!

Comment: I need inside reactjs project and it's not what I want, see jQueryscrollSpeed.js demo above

Comment: Of course, it's reactjs project you should add this event on button click